# Adding MKCircle to the annotations on the map - Problem with setting CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationcoordinate2d, mkcircle

Im trying to add MKCircle to the map annotation. Later it is going to be used to detect user in this area and check in (if you have any tips how to start with this later, I'd be grateful). For now here is my code, but i get an error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D.Type' to expected argument type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'`

Here is my code, do I need to add sth else?:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate{

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    struct Szczyt {
      var name: String
      var describtion: String
      var lattitude: CLLocationDegrees
      var longtitude: CLLocationDegrees
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBAction func mapTypeSegmentSelected(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                mapView.mapType = .standard
            case 1:
                mapView.mapType = .satellite
            default:
                mapView.mapType = .hybrid
            }
        }
  **let circle = MKCircle(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: 100)** //Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D.Type' to expected argument type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'

    let szczyty = [Szczyt(name: "one", describtion: "describtion one", lattitude: 50.333061725039226, longtitude: 16.708595782487315),
                   Szczyt(name: "Two", describtion: "Describtion two", lattitude: 50.444874478583854, longtitude: 20.896341184611302),
                   Szczyt(name: "Three", describtion: "Describiton three", lattitude: 50.555134079897516, longtitude: 15.884675411850157)]
    
 
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()
        findSthOnTheMap(szczyty)
        mapView.delegate = self
        
        }
        func checkLocationServices() {
          if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            checkLocationAuthorization()
          } else {
          }
        }
        func checkLocationAuthorization() {
          switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
          case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
           case .denied: 
           break
          case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
          case .restricted: 
           break
          case .authorizedAlways:
           break

          }
    }
    func findSthOnTheMap(_ szczyty: [Szczyt]) {
      for szczyt in szczyty {
        let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotations.title = szczyt.name
        annotations.subtitle = szczyt.opis
        annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:
          szczyt.lattitude, longitude: szczyt.longtitude)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotations)
        mapView.addOverlay(circle)
      }
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }
        let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")
        switch annotation.title!! {
            case "one":
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.86, green: 0.99, blue: 0.79, alpha: 1.00)
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "example")
            case "two":
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.80, green: 0.98, blue: 0.73, alpha: 1.00)
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "example")
            case "three":
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.73, green: 0.98, blue: 0.68, alpha: 1.00)
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "example")
            default:
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor.green
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "example")
        }
        return annotationView
    }
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
        return circleRenderer
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `CLLocationCoordinate2D` as it is as opposed to coordinates to make an MKCircle object?

Comment: @ElTomato now I know how to properly use the structure of this variable. @Shadowrun already explained it and now Im trying to use statemant ```let circle = MKCircle(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 54.865061725039226, longitude: 13.708595782487315), radius: 200)``` to all of my model objects in szczyty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression:

```
let circle = MKCircle(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: 100)
```

Is like saying `3 + Int`

You need to provide a *value* of *type* `CLLocationCoordinate2D`

You provided the *type itself* as an argument to MKCircle's center parameter

Make an instance like `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)` to provide an actual coordinate where you want the circle to be centered

Update: if you want to add circular annotations for all of these model objects, then perhaps something like this is what you want:

Note some typos:

```
struct Szczyt {
    let name: String
    let describtion: String   // description
    let lattitude: CLLocationDegrees // latitude
    let longtitude: CLLocationDegrees // longitude
}
```

Add a computed property in an extension on our model that lets us easily get its CLLocationCoordinate2D

```
extension Szczyt {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        .init(latitude: lattitude, longitude: longtitude)
    }
}

let szczyty = [Szczyt(name: "one", describtion: "describtion one", lattitude: 50.333061725039226, longtitude: 16.708595782487315),
               Szczyt(name: "Two", describtion: "Describtion two", lattitude: 50.444874478583854, longtitude: 20.896341184611302),
               Szczyt(name: "Three", describtion: "Describiton three", lattitude: 50.555134079897516, longtitude: 15.884675411850157)]
```

Make an array of MKCircle objects from all of the model objects

```
let circles = szczyty.map {
    MKCircle(center: $0.coordinate, radius: 100)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got you - I did not described the problem in details - how to use var longtitude an var lattitude from the struct Szczyt as a value to provide coordinate? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can I use extension inside the class in this place?

Comment: Yes - If I add extension in this place -Declaration is only valid at file scope.

Comment: You have to define extensions at file scope, so not nested within an existing type, like a struct, enum or class. Your struct is nested inside ViewController type, so you would need to say "extension ViewController.Szczyt { ... }" - or just add the "var coordinate" computed property inside the struct Szczyt itself

Comment: Ok, I just added var coordinate inside struct Sczyt and it should be ok: ```struct Szczyt {
      let name: String
      let opis: String
      let lattitude: CLLocationDegrees
      let longtitude: CLLocationDegrees
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
            .init(latitude: lattitude, longitude: longtitude)
        }
    }
``` but when I use ```let circles = szczyty.map``` it gets me an error ```Cannot use instance member 'szczyty' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available``` Should I use a property before the object is init?

Comment: I did sth like this: ```private(set) var circles: [MKCircle]```and added circles = szczyty.map in viewdidload: ``` override func viewDidLoad() { circles = szczyty.map {
                    MKCircle(center: $0.coordinate, radius: 200)
                }
        }``` But in the place when I want to add overlay to the map i receive Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: ```mapView.addOverlay(circles as! MKOverlay)```

Comment: Your force cast is wrong - an array of MKCircle's is not a single MKOverlay. At best you could say you want an array of MKOverlay's - avoid force casts. Think carefully about the types involved

Comment: Thanks, so circles wasnt initilized because of circles=szczyty.map was in viewdidload - just added ```mapView.addOverlays(circles!)``` in view did load and it worked. Thanks for a tip!